# Discord.py : on_message() not working on some servers

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am writing a script for a client that notifies you if someone asks for an editor in some specific channels.

However, the on_message() function doesn't detect messages on two servers (which are both partnered servers) but works on any other.

(Note that it is also running as a selfbot).

Here is the code:

```
import discord
import time
import json


with open('config.json', 'r') as f:

    json_f = json.load(f)

    TOKEN = json_f['Token']
    words = json_f['words']
    channels = json_f['channels']
    blacklist = json_f['blacklisted']
    export_channel = json_f['export_channel']
    blackl_users = json_f['blacklisted_users']


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready !\nLogged as :', client.user.name)



@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    send_in = client.get_channel(export_channel)


    if message.author.id in blackl_users:
        return

    for i in blacklist:
        if i in message.content.lower():
            return

    if (message.channel.id in channels)==False:
        return


    for i in words:
        if i in message.content.lower():

            c_time = time.localtime(time.time())
            m_time = str(c_time.tm_hour) + ':' + str(c_time.tm_min) + ' the ' + str(c_time.tm_mon) + '/' + str(c_time.tm_mday) + '/' + str(c_time.tm_year)

            title_content = 'Message found in the server "' + str(message.guild) + '" :'

            desc_content = '**Channel name :** #' + message.channel.name + '\n**Channel ID : **' + str(message.channel.id) + '\n\n**By : **' + str(message.author) + '\n**Author ID :** ' + str(message.author.id) + '\n\n**At : **' + m_time + '\n\n**Message ID : **' + str(message.id) + '\n**Message content :**\n' + message.content


            embed = discord.Embed(title=title_content, description=desc_content, color=0x7d34eb)

            await send_in.send(embed=embed)

            return



client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do not use selfbots. They are [against Discord's Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/discord/status/938576069690560513) and will most likely get your account IP banned.

Comment: I know but as I said, its not for me
I am making it upon a client request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend discord.py for writing selfbots (read last sentence of this answer if you really want to use discord.py). Discord.py is maintained for bot accounts and by using it you risk running something that the client doesn't normally do (and therefore, flaggable by discord).
Anyways, user accounts require to first be subscribed to a guild in order to listen to messages from that guild (this is an op14, [termed "LazyRequest" by Luna](https://arandomnewaccount.gitlab.io/discord-unofficial-docs/lazy_guilds.html)).
I'm not sure how to do this with discord.py, but I do know how to do it with a different wrapper called [discum](https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M). Here's how:

```py
import discum
bot = discum.Client(token='token here')

@bot.gateway.command
def somefunctionname(resp):
    if resp.event.ready_supplemental:
        bot.gateway.request.lazyGuild(FIRSTGUILDID, {FIRSTCHANNELID: [[0,99]]}, typing=True, threads=False, activities=True, members=[])
        bot.gateway.request.lazyGuild(SECONDGUILDID, {SECONDCHANNELID: [[0,99]]}, typing=True, threads=False, activities=True, members=[])
    if resp.event.message:
        print(resp.raw) #print the raw response from discord

bot.gateway.run()
```

Note that discum is only written and maintained to work only on user accounts.

And just found this...here's another solution ig if you want to use discord.py (same general idea as the code above):
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6340#issuecomment-765868893